# Ошибка RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Я выяснил, что ошибка заключается в reply_markup (другие markup работают), но не могу понять, почему возникает ошибка

main.py:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda v: v.data == 'myb_ru')
async def may_bags_enasdg(callbackquery: types.CallbackQuery):

await bot.edit_message_text(
    text = '...',
    message_id = callbackquery.message.message_id,
    chat_id = callbackquery.message.chat.id
)

await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(
    reply_markup = myb_ru_kb,
    message_id = callbackquery.message.message_id,
    chat_id = callbackquery.message.chat.id
)
```

keyboard.py:

```
myb_ru_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 2)

myb_buy_ru = InlineKeyboardButton(
text = 'Купить',
callback_data = 'myb_buy_ru'`)

myb_bags_ru_back = InlineKeyboardButton(
text = 'Назад↩️',
callback_data = 'pre_sale_ru'
)
```

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки с полным стэктрейсом

Comment: Текст ошибки слишком большой. Добавил в вопрос скрин, в котором небольшая часть ошибки

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить/обновить aiogram, такое впечатление что там какая-то бесконечная рекурсия возникла. Либо вы туда какую-то бесконечно вложенную структуру передали (типа список вложенный в самого себя)